# Error "The selected function was provided the incorrect number of arguments"

Tags: commcare

I have the following expression and keep getting an error message that says: **"The selected function was provided the incorrect number of arguments"**

```
concat(if(selected( danger_signs, 'convulsions_unconsciousness'), "Convulsions or Unconsciousness,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs, 'headaches_vision'), "Headaches or Blurred Vision,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs, 'vaginal_bleeding'), "Vaginal Bleeding,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs, 'vaginal_discharge'), "Vaginal Discharge,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs = 'swelling_face_hands'), "Swelling face or hands,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs, 'fever'), "Fever,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs, 'breaking_water'), "Breaking Water,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs, 'abdominal_pain'), "Abdominal Pain,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs, 'excessive_tiredness'), "Excessive tiredness,", ""), if(selected( danger_signs, 'lower_leg_pain'), "Lower leg pain,", ""), if( urinary_urgency = 'yes', "Urinary Urgency,", ""), if( referral_reason_other = "", "", "Other:"),  referral_reason_other)
```

Comment: The error was in this chunk: if(selected( danger_signs = 'swelling_face_hands'), "Swelling face or hands,", "")... The expression should use a comma instead of an equal sign

Answer (score 3):

The wording is weird on this error message. It means that the `selected` function was provided the wrong number of arguments. If you look at your expression, you will see a chunk that says:

```
selected( danger_signs = 'swelling_face_hands')
```

However, [`selected` takes two arguments](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Functions#CommCareFunctions-selected), and you have only provided 1. Perhaps you meant:

```
selected( danger_signs, 'swelling_face_hands')
```